# Service or IntentService for database queries?

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I'm trying to understand the best use of Services in Android for database queries (newbie). The service should enable a connection (via internet) to a database that is used to query a database from an activity.

My understanding is that this can be achieved using a Bound Service, i.e., multiple clients can be bound to the service each of which has access to the service's methods. However, I'm unsure as to whether to extend the `Service` class or its subclass `IntentService` for this situation.

Ideally the service should connect to the database once at the start of the service, e.g. in its `onCreate` method, and disconnect in the service's `onDestroy` method. The service will then have various methods that use this connection to query the database.

So, is there a difference between extending the `Service` class and starting a new thread in `onCreate` for the database connection, and extending the `IntentService` class and starting the connection in `onCreate` (i.e. `IntentService` initiates its own worker thread)?

When you bind to an `IntentService` is it kept alive until all activities have unbound from it?

Is this the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most natural and recommended way is to create a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Content Provider already implements reasonable life cycle and solves many other problems you'll surely encounter trying to implement such service from scratch.

Comment: Thanks msh. Can you use content providers to access data on a server, i.e., not on the device? The server also has a number of php scripts that I'd like the app to execute to return results. So I'm not sure that content providers provide a solution, but I haven't used them before.

Comment: Sure, why not? You can use content provider to access any data that can be represented as a cursor or a file.

Comment: Okay, sounds interesting. Will have to investigate further.